# How to set default line spacing in a .cls file?

Tags: line-spacing, documentclass-writing, setspace

I am writing a document class where I want to set the default line spacing to be 1.5. How can I use the `setspace` package to achieve this? More particularly, where in my .cls file should I mention `\onehalfspacing`?
I have tried modifying `\baselinestretch`, but it does not work when I add `\RequirePackage{setspace}` in the .cls file.

Comment: Wouldn't `\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` be sufficient?

Comment: @egreg: When trying to compile with `\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}`, I am getting the error:  
Package: `setspace' 6.7 <2000/12/01>  
)  
! Undefined control sequence.  
\setstretch ...ef \baselinestretch {#1}\@currsize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your comment says, that `\@currsize` is undefined. It is set by `\@setfontsize`, which is called by LaTeX font size commands such as `\Large`, `\small` etc.

So you could fix it by defining \@currsize yourself, such as by

```
\let\@currsize\normalsize
```

but I recommend to define a font size in your class before you load `setspace`, which fixes it. Here's an example from `bk10.clo`, loaded by the `book` class:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
```

Comment: The command `\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` must go after a `\LoadClass` command (if used).

Answer (score 3):

The new documentclass is baz.cls

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{baz.cls}
\PassOptionsToPackage{onehalfspacing}{setspace}
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{baz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```